# Hiding link if div empty?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a document where I want to hide a link if there is no available content. So what I want is that if {{Story}} is empty (that content is retrieved from a document but you don't have to care bout that), the link Show/Hide Story should be hidden.

I can't use jQuery because the code is not for a real website but for a program with an integrated browser.

```
<br><div style="margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="toggle('Historia');">Show/Hide Story</a>
<div id="Historia" style="display: none; font-size: 12px; overflow: auto"><p align="justify">{{Story}}</p></div></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zaGT2/

Comment: you mean on document load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `window.onload` to a funciton and in that function get the `p` tag check its content length if it is 0 hide the show/hide button

```
window.onload = function(){
    var container = document.getElementById("Historia")
                            .getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    if(container.textContent.length==0){
        document.getElementById("showhide").style.display = "none";   
    }
};
```

I added an id to the show/hide button so that `getElementById` could be used

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pevans02/zaGT2/10/)

Comment: what if one has looots of links and stories on one page?

Comment: That would depend on OP's integrated browser's capabilities. If it does not have access to like `querySelector`, `getElementsByClassName` etc polyfills would be needed, or plan out a specific html structure so that we could just get a single element by its id and all its direct children were the links and just have id to the stories stored on an attribute or something.